# Subsetting the duplicate company identifiers in the company level data

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains the financial information of various companies such as revenue, and profits in the year. The companies are given a unique ID. I would like to subset the dataset to include all the duplicated company ID and their related financial information.

I have tried the function duplicated() but it either hangs or provide an error as the dataframe has over 200 million records. Could anyone help me with this? Thank you as I am still unfamiliar with R.

I have tried the following:

```
Duplicate <- DF[duplicated(DF$ID),]
```

where DF is the name of the dataframe and ID is the company ID. But the code could not run and I am stuck.

```
#ID#  #Revenue#  #Profit#
 1      50          10
 2      20          10
 2      20          10
 2      20          10
 3      10          0
 4      20          5
 4      20          5
```

I want a dataframe that includes all the IDs with Company 2 and 4 since they are duplicates

Comment: have done so :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

The function `duplicated(DF$ID)` returns a logical vector of same length as rows in `DF`, indicating whether the value at each position has been seen before. So for the following string, `duplicated` will return

```
1  2  2  2  2  3  4  4
F  F  T  T  T  F  F  T
```

and hence, your code line returns the subset of rows where the ID has is a duplicate *but not the first instance*.

For me it is unclear whether you need just a reduced list of which IDs appear multiple times, the entire rows of duplicate records (including/excluding first record), or whether you are considering looking at duplicate *records* or just duplicate *IDs*.

To get which IDs appear multiple times, count them:

```
count <- table(DF$ID)
names(count[count > 1])
```

Note: `names()` returns a character vector.
To get the records where the IDs appear multiple times, we can:

```
Duplicate <- DF[DF$ID %in% as.integer(names(count[count > 1])), ] # wrapped in as.integer, as I suspect your ID column is an integer vector.
```

or, try with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
Duplicate <- DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  add_count() %>%
  filter(n > 1)
```

Might be quicker if you have 200 mio rows.

*Update:*

To get only the first(*) occurrence of each ID, simply

```
DF[!duplicated(DF$ID),]
```

*first occurrence depends entirely on the ordering of the data.frame.

But do note that you must be entirely sure whether the entire records are actually duplicate, so you would definitely want to look into if duplicate records differ in any way.

If you have multiple columns that you regard sufficient to be duplicated, try with `dplyr::distinct`:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% distinct(ID, Revenue, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

If you do not include `.keep_all = TRUE`, only the named columns will be returned.

#### You have 200 mio rows

At this point I would say you've fallen outside the scope of R - at least using R naively.

If you have access to a database server (MySQL, MS SQL, PostSQL, etc.), you should definitely leverage that! I assume you are just starting on the data cleaning and these database engines have some powers for working with data of this size.

If you do not, you can offload it into an SQLite database file with `RSQLite`-package. It allows you to run many of the same operations with SQL. For your case, we can retrieve the set of rows with duplicated IDs with:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID
  FROM DF
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING count(*) > 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM DF
INNER JOIN cte USING (ID);
```

Once loaded your data frame into the table `DF` and using an appropriate index.

To get *DISTINCT* rows you do not have the same luxury as `dplyr::distinct`, but you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM DF;
```

If you however want to retrieve all columns that are distinct on a subset of columns, window function could be the way (unless you have a distinct row ID -- which SQLite implicitly always has):

```
SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, column2, ...) AS rownumber
FROM DF
WHERE rownumber = 1;
```

SQLite wouldn't like that, so it would have to be wrapped in a subquery or view. But SQLite, with its implicit rowid you could do:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT min(_ROWIID_) AS rowid
  FROM DF
  GROUP BY ID, column2, ...
)
SELECT DF.*
FROM DF
INNER JOIN cte USING (rowid);
```

Comment: Thank you it works well! I was wondering if you know how I could remove the duplicates from the original dataframe?

Comment: I first wanted to see all the duplicates of the dataset. Afterwhich, I would want to keep only the first instance in the full dataset.